# Migrating data from Paradox to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, paradox

The company I work for has a very old system that uses Paradox.
I need to rewrite this system and I need to migrate the data from Paradox to SQL Server 2008.
How do I do this?

Comment: Tried creating a DSN with the paradox ODBC driver then using the ODBC option in sql servers import wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it was possible to log into the Paradox database, copy and paste the data into Excel and then import the data into SQL Server in the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something exactly the same for a company I am working for

There are a few options

Export data in csv files through paradox

Or if your really lazy like me get the free trial for ESF database migration tool

you can select the entire Schema or database you want to convert

and convert everything all at once.

I was a little skeptical at first so I played with the free trial before buying it, but I must say it was worth buying.

Hope this helps it had me annoyed for a few months.